# Convert IDispatch* to a string?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I am converting an old VB COM object (which I didn't write) to C++ using ATL.  One of the methods, according to the IDL, takes an `IDispatch*` as a parameter and the documentation and samples for this method claim that you can pass either a string (which is the progid of an object that will be created and used by the control) or an `IDispatch*` to an object that has already been created.  How on earth do I implement this in ATL?

For example, the IDL:

```
[id(1)] HRESULT Test(IDispatch* obj);
```

The samples (which are all JScript):

```
obj.Test("foo.bar");
```

or

```
var someObject = new ActiveXObject("foo.bar");
obj.Test(someObject);
```

To make matters even more bizarre the actual VB code that implements this method actually declares the 'obj' parameter as a string!  However, it all seems to work.

Can you even pass a string to a COM method that takes an `IDispatch*`?  If so, can I determine that the `IDispatch*` is actually a string in my C++ ATL code?  Even better, if it's an `IDispatch` that implements a specific interface I will want to call methods on it, or instantiate an object if it's a string.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Just to be sure. The vb code has a method taking a string argument but when you extract the IDL from the .dll it looks like the methods takes an IDispatch instead?

Comment: @Alexandre - yes, the IDL (which was supplied with the VB source - I didn't extract it) shows the method taking an IDispatch* but the VB code itself declares the param as a String.  The JScript examples use both a string and an interface as described.

Comment: If you try to pass an IDispatch to a parameter declared as a primitive type, its default property is evaluated and passed as the actual parameter value. So, yes, this is a valid piece of code.

Comment: agree with Alexandre, variant is the best type to be used in this case. You'll be able to handle whatever types supported in a backward compatible fashion

Comment: OK, I changed my code to use a VARIANT which I can then check for VT_BSTR or VT_DISPATCH and it works perfectly.  If Alexandre posts this an an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @wqw: could you elaborate, maybe in an answer? This sounds more bizarre than usual, even for COM and VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the method so that it takes a VARIANT argument and check the actual type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have instance `obj` of VB6 class `Class1` and try to assign it to a primitive type like this

```
    Dim str As String
    str = obj
```

... then `Class1`'s default property gets evaluated. Same rule applies for method calls

```
Function MyFunc(str As String)
   ...
End Function

   MyFunc obj
```

Last method call will succeed only if `Class1` has a default property defined and `obj`'s default property value can be cast to `String`.